# (SAS)how to make prediction to new data using a trained logistic regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, sas, logistic-regression, prediction

I have a simulated dataset for personal loans, it contains borrowers' financial history and their requested loans. I'm trying to write a logistic regression model to assess loan status - current(0) or default(1)

I have already splitter the dataset into 70%train and 30%test
my code looks like:

```
/*Logistic regression*/
ods graphics on;
proc logistic data=train outmodel=model.log plots=all;
    class purpose term grade yearsemployment homeownership incomeVerified;
    model bad_good (event='0') =purpose term grade yearsemployment homeownership incomeVerified
                    date
                    isJointApplication
                    loanAmount
                    interestRate
                    monthlyPayment
                    annualIncome
                    dtiRatio
                    lengthCreditHistory
                    numTotalCreditLines
                    numOpenCreditLines
                    numOpenCreditLines1Year
                    revolvingBalance
                    revolvingUtilizationRate
                    numDerogatoryRec
                    numDelinquency2Years
                    numChargeoff1year
                    numInquiries6Mon                    
/
    selection=stepwise
    details
    lackfit;
    score data= test out=score1;
    store log_model;
run;

/*Score model*/
proc logistic inmodel=model.log;
    score data=train out=score2 fitstat;
run;

proc logistic inmodel=model.log;
    score data=test out=score3 fitstat;
run;

/*confusion matrix*/
proc freq data=score2;
    tables f_bad_good*i_bad_good / nocol norow; 
run;

proc freq data=score3;
    tables f_bad_good*i_bad_good / nocol norow; 
run;
```

My next step is to use this trained model to make predictions to a new prod data, update that data and store it. How would I do that?

Also I wonder if anyone could take a look at my code and see if there's anything I should improve on.  I'm new to SAS and statistics, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, and your code is looking great so far. When scoring data in production, there are two things that you need:

- An input dataset
- A model to apply to the data

It looks like you are storing your model as a binary file that can be processed with `proc plm`, but you do not need to do it this way since you've already saved your model with the `outmodel` statement in `proc logistic`. The `store` statement is just another way to store the model if you'd like to use it that way, but I would stick with `outmodel` since it's a little more straight-forward. Let's look at a really simple example using `sashelp.class`:

```
data train
     prod;

    set sashelp.class;

    if(_N_ LE 15) then output train;
        else output prod;
run;

proc logistic data=train outmodel=sasuser.logmodel;
    model sex = age height weight;
run;
```

We've saved our model into `sasuser.logmodel`. Now we want to score new production data. In a new SAS program, you'll use code that looks like this:

```
proc logistic inmodel=sasuser.logmodel;
    score data=prod out=predictions;
run;
```

Assume `prod` is your new production data coming in.

Let's take a look at the `predictions` output dataset:

```
Name    Sex Age Height  Weight  F_Sex   I_Sex   P_F             P_M
Robert  M   12  64.8    128     M       M       0.0023352346    0.9976647654
Ronald  M   15  67      133     M       M       0.1822442826    0.8177557174
Thomas  M   11  57.5    85      M       M       0.148103678     0.851896322
William M   15  66.5    112     M       F       0.7322326277    0.2677673723
```

The column `I_Sex` (which stands for Into) is the prediction. The other columns starting with `P` are probabilities for predicting male or female, and the column starting with `F` (which stands for From) is the actual value. In reality, you will not have this actual value since production data is predicting an unknown value.

It's generally a good practice to always append your predictions to a final master dataset and give them a timestamp. You'll want to keep a history of your predictions and see how they change over time, especially if you need to debug something in the future. This may be a production database, or it could even be a SAS dataset. Below is an example of how you could do this.

```
/* This ensures you're always using the exact same timestamp down to the ms */
%let now = %sysfunc(datetime());

/* Add a timestamp and clean up the dataset */
data predictions;
    set predictions;

    prediction_ts = &now;

    format prediction_ts datetime.;

    keep name age height weight i_sex prediction_ts;
    rename i_sex = predicted_sex;
run;

/* Append to the master dataset if it exists */
%if(%sysfunc(exist(master_dataset) ) ) %then %do;
    proc append base=master_dataset data=predictions force;
    run;
%end;

    /* Otherwise, create it */
    %else %do;
        data master_dataset;
            set predictions;
        run;
    %end;
```

You can then pull the most recent prediction for any given primary key. For example:

```
proc sql;
    select *
    from master_dataset
    having prediction_ts = max(prediction_ts)
    ;
quit;
```

You could have a separate process that applies actual values as well to see how the predictions compare to reality. This extends beyond the scope of what you're asking, but this is a fantastic question that you have asked and is very, very important for productionalizing a model.